# Maven get latest of dependency

Tags: java, maven, github

I have two projects in GitHub one is a core and the other depends on it. I am constantly updating both still and need a way to always have the latest version of the dependency when working on the project.

I tried setting up a maven project and depending on the core plugin using JitPack but since my repos are private it wouldn't let me without a subscription. Are there any other programs that work with private repos for free?

I tried searching online but don't know exactly what type of program it would be since I am new to working with all this.

Comment: You can opt for something like nexus `https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-oss`, but you have to host it somewhere yourself which involves payment for a machine in the cloud, so still not free.

Comment: Please search before asking a question. The linked duplicate was not difficult to find

Comment: Not familiar with jitpack but it sounds like a build server and repository manager all in one (?). Jenkins and Artifactory are both free solutions for this purpose. But it sounds to me like you don't need to publish anything at all. If you `mvn install` from your dependency project, you can refer to that artifact from your dependent project on your local machine without ever having published anywhere.

Comment: Have both projects open in your ide when developing.  Good maven support should recognize this.

Comment: Also, unless you have good reason to, then why not just have the project openly available?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I'm developing a game plugin and don't want the players to be able to steal my code and reuse it or for them to find possible glitches and bypasses that could then be abused on the server.

Comment: Then just put your two maven projects in the same repository as submodules.